# Nothing will insert into my database

Tags: php, mysql, html

Here is the code:
      contact_us2.php

```
   <form id="form1" method="post" action="enquires.php">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Form to database example</legend>
  <label for="text">
      <span>Comments:</span>
    <textarea id="text" name="comments" rows="4" cols="80"></textarea>
      </label>
      <label for="name">
     <span>Name:</span>
      <input id="name" type='text' name='name' size='50'/>
       </label>
      <label for="email">
    <span>Email:</span>
  <input id="email" type='text' name='email' size='50'/>
      </label>

     <label for="submit1" id="submit"><span>&nbsp;</span>
      <input id="submit1" class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
      </label>
     </fieldset>
    </form>


                 enquires.php

                <?php
        session_start();
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
        require('authenticate.php');
        include_once"../scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
        $name  = $_post['name'];
        $email = $_post['email'];
        $comments = $_post['comments'];
        echo "$email";
        // Query the body section for the proper page
        mysql_select_db("hardware_cms" )or die (mysql_error());
        $sqlCommand = MYSQL_QUERY("INSERT INTO enquires (id, name, email,      comments)". "VALUES ('NULL', '$name', '$email', '$comments')") or die (mysql_error()); 
        ?>
```

There is no errors. The only thing that is inserted into the database is the id. I think the problem is in contact_us2.php.  I'm new to html and php sorry if this is a silly question.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [**red box**](http://php.net/mysql-connect)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, try [this article](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.api.choosing). If you care to learn, [here is good PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: thank you is that why my code will not work?

Comment: @user1680558 That's not why it doesn't work, but it is important enough to stop what you're doing right now and go read about what Mihai suggested and implement database queries using one of those ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the php code because you have to use $_POST and don't $_post

```
 $name  = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $comments = $_POST['comments'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `$_post` with `$_POST` and see what happens.

Also, PLEASE sanitize your SQL inputs  (either by using mysql_real_escape_string, or better - by using PDO prepared statements).

Comment: yeah. i believe the asker will see a new row without values in db if he uses $_post. LOL

Comment: Yes that is a good idea thank you :)  and the  $_POST did work.